# Bootstrap popover is not functional only in Windows 8 phone but its functional in android phone

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8

I m building a hybrid application for multiple platform such windows , android and IOS.

Following is the snippet for Popover which is working in android and IOS phone

```
 <button id="alarmbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-contentwrapper=".myAnalyticscontent" rel="Analyticspopover" style="width: 32%;"><img src="resources/images/alarms.png" /></button>
```

and script code for this popover

```
 <div class="myAnalyticscontent" id="myAnalyticscontent"> <!-- Here i    define     my content and add an attribute data-contentwrapper t0 a selector-->
     <h3 id="alarmlabel" >Set Alarm Type</h3>
      <hr id="alarmform"></hr>
  <script>
    $('[rel=Analyticspopover]').popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'top',
        content: function () {
            return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
        }
    });
 </script>         
</div>
```

The Above piece of code is functional in Android Phone, but in windows phone this code was crashing because of inner HTML exception. So I added

```
<script src="thirdparty/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
```

because of this No exception is seen,but Popover also is not functional in windows phone.

Comment: Any one who can help on this?